# How to use image picker?

Tags: javascript, html

i m a beginner and wanted to use image picker from : https://rvera.github.io/image-picker/
        but have no idea how i can install it in my code ... any help pls ? thank you

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>picker</title>
  <script src="image-picker.js"></script>
  <script src="image-picker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="image-picker.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <script>
     $("select").imagepicker()
     $("select").imagepicker()
 </script>
<select class="image-picker">
  <option data-img-src="test.png" data-img-class="first" data-img-alt="Page 1" value="1">  Page 1  </option>
  <option data-img-src="test.png" data-img-alt="Page 2" value="2">  Page 2  </option>
  <option data-img-src="test.png" data-img-alt="Page 3" value="3">  Page 3  </option>

  <option data-img-src="tst.png" data-img-alt="Page 4" data-img-class="last" value="4"> Page 4 </option>
</select>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are initializing it before you make it, you are also not including picker CSS:
 try this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>picker</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="image-picker.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="image-picker.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select class="image-picker show-html">
      <option data-img-src="test.png" data-img-class="first" data-img-alt="Page 1" value="1">  Page 1  </option>
      <option data-img-src="test.png" data-img-alt="Page 2" value="2">  Page 2  </option>
      <option data-img-src="test.png" data-img-alt="Page 3" value="3">  Page 3  </option>
      <option data-img-src="tst.png" data-img-alt="Page 4" data-img-class="last" value="4"> Page 4 </option>
    </select>
    <script>
       $("select").imagepicker()
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```